# Custom class type does not support classes with static methods

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-generics

I tried to map classes to strings. Something like:

`map.add(ClassName, 'my string');`

for this I created a custom type:

`type NoConstructor<T> = Pick<T, keyof T>;`

then I define a map likes this:

`const map: Map<NoConstructor<typeof Device>, string> = new Map();`

while `map.add(ClassName, 'my string');` works, `map.get(instanceOfClassName.constructor)` only works as long as a class has no static methods. As soon as a class has static methods, I get an error by TypeScript:

> Argument of type 'Function' is not assignable to parameter of type 'NoConstructor'.
> Type 'Function' is missing the following properties from type 'NoConstructor': getInputs, getOutputs

Why do static methods on the class influence my custom type? To me this doesn't make sense. Can anyone elaborate why this is the case and how to fix this code example?

[Example on typescriptlang.org/play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAQwEYGcZQQY3pgNglFOAEWADcBLTYOAbwCg4m4wBXJXKuAc2BgGUYCGKxQAKAJQAuOGigUAdtzqNmaqH1ZQFcAOQAzCBF0BuVUwC%209cy3adMsoTC68YASQVsY46XQDaANbAAJ4ycorcALoyCqwAtkjAUBYqauqa2nQWZmpWNmwcXGjCLnwA8qwwXj4ytIEhYegR0XCxCUkpDGnMGiKZtNk2Vnl4BESklNQAgnCgMMAKACbj5FQ0DPR5MMFgNAByEADCEApyrNjQADwAKgB8cAC8cAAKVAE3ADRwQcEQ%20nB3Mz0UCQWBwRbAfQIVi4HD4QgkVbUACqYEWwiS9C6zDA8jIGLgGgQixOuGCcDiCDAMgAslTLgdjqd0OcYFdtrs-ojJsBbl9wkp7k8FMAAO5wOlgSRAtQFeyIRaLMQQnnXHbAGSMk5nC5QS4c4BciZrPlwVhojFQRryJQSVLdOAwAAWFBQADpKWA3Sg%20MqkcA1bsvub0fMoBIcsw8rK7FwQxi-TyZMbqL4yBAKIt7d1MNr4BoUDD4E9na6PVS3a5E2s3bnmVBWdAIzY1BR-mIC0XHg8nqwlpDFMBFnbsQ7mM6oBBxSLxQBRKCTqBiAAGhwQCgUEHg8fm4P9cC5Br0ABJaCqa3WdWyoG6FAg4sALLoYhAzRaw3BDH3Fsvm2Pow6l4QLgwBurgEDcB2wCFrCf5Rps1iXvA54ou%20SSPK0YrcmsqKhkk0rWChwC4ZabrEkqKbAFMXy6CgEAPqWSi6M29BESRYZujuwBiDO2HTJIzZAA):

```
export abstract class Device {
    public getStatus(): string {
        return 'foo';
    }

    // Remove this one
    public static getInputs(): {[key: string]: number} {
        return {};
    }

    // and remove this one, and the code works
    public static getOutputs(): {[key: string]: number} {
        return {};
    }
}

class DeviceA extends Device {

}

type NoConstructor<T> = Pick<T, keyof T>;

export default class DeviceUpdater
{
    private readonly map: Map<NoConstructor<typeof Device>, string> = new Map();

    public add(deviceType: NoConstructor<typeof Device>, updater: string) {
        this.map.set(deviceType, updater);
    }

    public update(device: Device): void {
        const result = this.map.get(device.constructor);
        if (result === undefined) {
            throw new Error(`Cannot update device of type '${device.constructor.name}': no updater found`);
        }

        console.log(result);
    }
}

const deviceUpdater = new DeviceUpdater();

deviceUpdater.add(DeviceA, 'something');

deviceUpdater.update(new DeviceA());
```

Comment: IIRC the problem is that TS doesn't derive `instanceOfClassName.constructor` to have type `typeof ClassName`, but rather to the generic `Function`. However, what is `NoConstructor<typeof Device>` even trying to achieve? You could just as well put `unknown` there. Are you ever using the keys stored in the `map` for anything, and require them to have a specific interface?

Comment: @Bergi I want to ensure that only classes can be set as key that extend `Device`. In the example above `DeviceA` would be a valid value. And it must only accept an existing class name. Not a random value. `unknown` would solve it, but then I can set anything.

Comment: Type of any class is `new(...args: any[])=>any` and not just `Function`

Comment: @captain-yossarianfromUkraine yes, that might be. But how do I get the class type from an actual instance then? `classInstance.constructor` doesn't work.